# Laravel share data to 404 page view

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a controller which extends BaseController and shares some data in all the views

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $id = Auth::id();
            } else {
                $id = Session::getId();
            }

            \Cart::session($id);

            $cart = \Cart::getContent();

            $total = \Cart::getTotal();
        
            View::share('cart', $cart);
            View::share('total', $total);

            return $next($request);
        });
    }

}
```

The issue is, it doesn't get shared in error pages like 404.

I'm using Laravel 8.75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error the issue was that web middleware was not being executed in error pages.

Added to `web.php`

```
    Route::fallback(function(){
       return view('errors.404');
    });
```

Also to `appServiceProvider.php boot()` (optional)

```
        View()->composer(['layouts.main'], function($view) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $id = Auth::id();
            } else {
                $id = Session::getId();
            }

            \Cart::session($id);

            $cart = \Cart::getContent();

            $total = \Cart::getTotal();

            $view->with([
                'cart' => $cart, 
                'total' => $total
            ]);
        });
```

The reason i put the auth checking inside the view composer callback is because middlewares have to be executed to be able to grab the user.

Answer (score 1):

First you should publish all the error pages using this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

Then, hopefully it will work. If it didn't work then include this logic in AppServiceProvider's boot() function instead of base Controller.

Comment: I don't want to publish all of them, i created a folder named errors with the 404 view, it does the work.

Comment: you can use laravel's error pages and place your own code in them.

Comment: That's exactly what i said i did, i just did not publish them all, just created the 404 page view, but this is not the issue.

Comment: You should publish them and then replace your own code in the blade files, this is what I'm saying.